# How to execute group of threads and be notified when group finishes

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a series of tasks waiting in a queue to get processed. These tasks are assigned to a group of threads. So I have like a 3 groups of threads where each group has a fixed amount of threads, lets say Group A1 had 4 threads, A2 had 4 and A3 has 8.

Now the first tasks goes to group A1, second to group A2 ...etc.
So I have now 4 threads processing task 1 and 4 processing tasks 2 and 8 processing task 3.

The main question, is there an easy facility to use to know when all threads in 1 group have finished processing their task so that I can perform some post-execution code and then assign another task to that group?

Currently I am doing all of this manually by maintaining Hashtable  of thread groups and in each one of my threads I have them send a "Death Signal" to its parent. And the parent is keeping track of how many threads in the group die until they all die, once all are dead I can continue.

So it's a lot of maintenance and debugging the code to make sure it works correctly is taking time. Is there any library or built in facility within Java that can do the above ?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), in particular [ExecutorService#invokeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

Comment: So I can have 3 ThreadPoolExecutors running in parallel? I've used one before but not so many in one go.

Comment: Yes, you should be able, so long as there are separate instances

Comment: When dispatching each item on the queue, consider using callable/runnable with executors instead of threads. If the executor count isn't sufficient for youre needs, consider using a semaphore to keep track of started/finished tasks.

Comment: OK Thanks, I guess I'll use multiple ThreadPoolExecutorService and use Callable interface.